# Windows 10 - Transition for Visual State changes

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to make my Windows 10 app utilize responsive design by using visual state triggers to change the width of a grid.  When the state changes, the width jumps to the next width.

Is there a way to smoothen this change with a transition or animation of some kind?

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <VisualStateGroup>
         <VisualState x:Name="DesktopWideState">
             <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                 <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1280" />
             </VisualState.StateTriggers>

             <VisualState.Setters>
                 <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Width"
                    Value="1000" />
             </VisualState.Setters>
         </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="DefaultState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
         </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a demo project or some more code that we can play with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VisualState` does contain the property `Storyboard`, so it's indeed possible to create storyboard-based animations based based on StateTriggers.

`VisualState.Setters` have been introduced to remove the noise that `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` within a Storyboard creates.

To add an animation to your example use the following:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState x:Name="DesktopWideState">
      <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1280" />
      </VisualState.StateTriggers>
      <VisualState.Storyboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="1000" EnableDependentAnimation="True" />
        </Storyboard>
      </VisualState.Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

**Do not use this example!** Why?

Because by animating `Width` you affect layout. That's why the animation is disabled by default and does only work by setting `EnabledDependentAnimation` to true. You will see, that this animation will stutter a lot.

Try to avoid dependent animations and use storyboard in your AdaptiveTriggers only for independent animations like *Transforms*.